# UDP Broadcasting Issue

Tags: java, network-programming, udp

I was trying a simple problem of sending some random numbers from server to client by UDP Broadcasting. As far as I know, if I broadcast to a specific ip address and port number, all the users who are connected to that channel will be able to listen. I have looked for sample codes in the internet and developed my code based on that. But whenever I try to run the codes, my server closes the socket before client can get anything.

The server code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      DatagramPacket packet;
      InetAddress address;
      DatagramSocket socket;

      System.out.println("Sending Numbers!");

      socket = new DatagramSocket();

      try {
          int n = 10;

          SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
          address = InetAddress.getByName("233.0.0.1");

          for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              int num = rand.nextInt(100);
              byte[] tmp = Integer.toString(num).getBytes();
              packet = new DatagramPacket (tmp, 0, address, 1502);
              socket.send(packet);
              System.out.println("Number has been sent!");
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      } finally {
          try {
              socket.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Error2: " + e);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The client code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      // Initialization
      int n = 10;

      // Create the socket
      int port = 1502;
      DatagramSocket socket;
      DatagramPacket packet = null;

      socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          socket.receive (packet);
          byte[] numb = packet.getData();
          int num = ByteBuffer.wrap(numb).getInt();
          System.out.println(Integer.toString(num));
      }
  }

}
```

Then, I tried to compile each code using javac and java.

```
javac Server.java
java package_name.Server
```

I am running the Server first using the above method, then Client. I get NullPointerException for client. It would be really helpful if I understand what am I doing wrong here.

I am running them in command window. For server, I get this
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tzvJ.jpg)
And for Client: [Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1U8D.jpg)

**Edit:** I was able to communicate between Server and Client. However, I just keep getting the first number only. Moreover, if I initialize `Datagram` for size >2, I get `NumberFormatException`. This is the improved code.

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      DatagramPacket packet;
      InetAddress address;
      DatagramSocket socket;

      System.out.println("Sending Numbers!");

      socket = new DatagramSocket();

      try {
          int n = 10;

          SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
          address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

          ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          PrintStream pout = new PrintStream( bout );

          for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              int num = rand.nextInt(100);
              pout.print(num);
              byte[] barray = bout.toByteArray();
              packet = new DatagramPacket (barray, barray.length, address, 1502);
              socket.send(packet);
              System.out.println("Number has been sent!");
              System.out.println(num);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      } finally {
          try {
              socket.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Error2: " + e);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      // Initialization
      int n = 10;

      // Create the socket
      int port = 1502;
      DatagramSocket socket;
      byte[] buf = new byte[2];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

      socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          socket.receive (packet);
          int num = Integer.parseInt(new String(packet.getData()));
          System.out.println(num);
      }
  }
}
```

What can be the issue now?

**Edit 2:** Finally, I have made it work. Just put `bout` and `pout` inside the `for` loop and it should work!

Comment: Are the client and server running on the same machine?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes

Comment: So why not use `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Tried using localhost before. Had the same issue. I saw a sample code where someone used this ip address and used that one.

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UseDatagramSockettosendoutandreceiveDatagramPacket.htm - main difference is that they are using a while loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have added the screenshots

Comment: It might be an issue. But I increased n to 100000. Still had the same issue

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you please check the edited question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize your `DatagramPacket` in your client - it can not be null

```
     int n = 10;

      // Create the socket
      int port = 1502;
      DatagramSocket socket;
      byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

      socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          socket.receive (packet);
          byte[] numb = packet.getData();
          int num = ByteBuffer.wrap(numb).getInt();
          System.out.println(Integer.toString(num));
      }
```

Also this code needs to be running before your `Server`

Comment: I have made some progress. I have used the `Datagram` initialization. I have also used the localhost ip. However, I keep receiving 0 (or at least that what the command window shows when I convert to integer). Can you tell me the reason?        And sorry for replying late. I was stuck with some other things!

Comment: For a start, in `byte[] barray = bout.toByteArray();`  `bout` does not have any value . Secondly, in `byte[] buf = new byte[2];` why restrict yourself to two bytes - maybe ok if you restrict sending to two bytes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I can't upvote it as I have less than 15 reputations